# What is a good brand for teflon pans?

Tags: cookware, teflon

I am going to buy a new teflon pan and seem to run into bad luck with cheaply made ones which flake off too quickly. Also can any good brand teflon pan withstand automatic dishwashers?

Comment: More important than a brand recommendation is understanding that Teflon is not designed for certain uses, in particular high temperatures. Before you pick a brand you want to refer back to this entry: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2287/is-teflon-dangerous.

Comment: That's right, I only really plan to use it for scrambled eggs.

Comment: I use All-Clad professionally in the kitchen. As long as the pan is hot before I add the food, I use the straight stainless steel.

Comment: @Zombies- you miss the point, if your pans are flaking and falling apart "too quickly" maybe it is _operator error_ (using them in an a manner not consistent with what the manufacturers recommend) rather than being cheaply made. If you attempt to use a Ferrari for off-roading, it didn't fall apart because it was cheap manufacturing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not a good idea to combine ANY teflon pan with an automatic dishwasher, regardless of what the manufacturer says.

But fortunately for you, I have handy the Cook's Illustrated from October 2010, which did a nonstick skillet (aka frying pan aka saute pan) review.  **According to them, even the best nonstick coatings won't survive more than a year or two of heavy use.  This makes proper care all the more important**. Brand also isn't a good indicator of coating quality, because many pan manufacturers buy coatings from the same suppliers.  To quote the article:

> Most cookware manufacturers don't make their own nonstick coating; they buy it from suppliers offering a menu of options, from basic to premium, and spray it on their pans.  It's similar to painting a room; the quality of nonstick coating is determined not only by what's in it but also by how carefully it's applied and cured, and how many coats the manufacturer decides to put on.

They found the **Tefal (T-Fal in the States) Professional Total Nonstick Fry Pan ($35)** had a nonstick coating that outperformed the other pans by a significant margin, probably due to its 5-layer nonstick coating (most pans use 2-3 layers).  The only fly in the ointment was its handle, which had rivets that loosened after abuse.  But, for $35 that isn't bad, doubly because **it outperformed the $150+ All-Clad nonstick pans** they used normally.

**If you're looking for something cheaper than that, I'd suggest you look at construction and not brand.  Pick a heavy pan (for its size), with either solid, thick-gauge aluminum OR a multi-ply construction.**  This combination ensures the pan will heat evenly and rapidly (crucial for eggs), and is resistant to warping (important if you use an electric range). If you're cooking eggs, avoid hard-anodized aluminum interiors, as they don't help prevent adhesion of eggs, and just cost more.  The nonstick layer should look thick and smooth, not slightly textured.

My most-used frying pan (the default egg pan) is a small T-Fal that cost all of $7. The important thing is that it has the right construction and I treat it correctly; I'm careful not to scratch the surface with utensils, I never use a scouring pad on it, and it can't go near the dishwasher.  This makes more of a difference than picking a fancy brand.

Comment: A great answer Bob.

Comment: Offtopic: Does the brand I know as Tefal sell in the States under T-Fal, or is a competitor able to get away with the name without a trademark lawsuit? Or did you just "shorten" the name as not to discuss brands openly?

Comment: @rumtscho: Edited b/c I'd forgotten about that. Tefal sells as T-Fal in the States as a result of a branding conflict with Dupont, who claim it is too similar to "teflon".  This makes sense as it is a combination of "TEFlon and ALuminum".  Also, if anyone feels the need, I can go into the particular testing methodology Cook's Illustrated used.  It is fairly rigorous and objective, I just left out the details for brevity.

Comment: +1 for Tefal. I'm lucky to have a factory store near though, otherwise they'd be outside my budget :)

Comment: no problem with dishwasher and Tefal for me, but I don't need salt in my dishwasher because of our water type, which makes a difference.