# Are stainless steel frypans oven safe?

Tags: oven, cookware, stainless-steel

I have a Cr-Ni stainless steel frypan which I'd like to toss in the oven. It doesn't have any plastic/wooden components ; the whole thing is SS including the handle.

Is it oven safe?

Answer (score 5):

Typically "oven safe" indicates that none of the components will break down in high heats. As there are no plastic or wooden components, and the utensil is all metal, it would appear that it is oven safe. Assuming there are no other chemical compounds used in the fry pan that would break down you should be good to go and toss it in the oven as long as you wear a mitt when you pull it out.

Comment: In addition to wearing a mitt when you pull it out, as soon as you put it down (especially if it's on a burner to make a pan sauce), stick a mitt over the handle (as though the handle was a hand). This prevents you grabbing the hot metal 15 seconds later when it's being an ordinary pan on a burner/counter that you have seen many times before and that never has a hot handle. (BTDT got the burn.)

Comment: Or get one of those thermal handle socks, [Lodge makes them](http://www.amazon.com/Lodge-Temp-Handle-Mitt-Black/dp/B00063RWG6/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1326814031&sr=8-1) to resist temperatures up to 450'F and proof against steam burns

Comment: Teflon, according to Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teflon#Safety , is prone to releasing highly poisonous gases once heated to above 260°C (which ovens can pull off easily).

Comment: @Mischa [There's plenty around](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6232/111)[about Teflon's (+/-)safety](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2287/15) and although I refer to "chemical compounds" generally, I do not think that by virtue of the pan having a Teflon coating it should be deemed necessarily "unsafe for oven use". Also, that is 260'C (500'F) with nothing in the pan. Per the answer to the second question, you can probably create a nice toxic plume, but you'll also be violating common sense and destroying the pan. Don't heat it above 500'F

Comment: @MischaArefiev: This isn't a non-stick pan, so I'm good