# Are non-stick frying pans safe?

Tags: non-stick

Are non-stick frying pans safe? Are there any studies that explored the subject? Tiny particles of that non-stick coating flake off and are consumed with food, inevitably. I guess it may not be very safe (although you don't have any other frying options if you can't heat oil for health reasons)

Comment: The safety of Teflon is already answered in several questions, including https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/66493/safe-to-use-non-sticky-pan-with-scratches/66641#66641 and https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2287/is-teflon-dangerous .  In short, Teflon is safe unless you overheat it.

Comment: In a world where pretty much all products are subject to extremely high safety standards in most countries, wouldn't it be absolutely shocking if users here could find convincing evidence that non-stick pans were dangerous, which manufacturers and governments had missed or ignored? They're hardly a rare item.

Comment: Consider the issue of microplastics. Perfectly legal but understudied and likely carcinogenic

Comment: They use [teflon in surgery](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7936093/). Until some clever bunch of scientists comes up with some solid new research on the topic, you're not going to get better info from cooks.

Comment: Sergey: but this isn't a biochemical science SE.  It's a cooking SE.  If the USFDA or the ESFA say something is safe, you're not going to find a contrary answer here.  If you just wanna hash it out, the chat is available.